# `INSERT INTO` query is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Please have a look at the following code

```
INSERT INTO `test2.key_word` SELECT * from `test.key_word`
```

I am using PHPMyAdmin. This query simply gives the error `No Database Selected` when run inside the `server 127.0.0.1` area. If I run this inside query inside the SQL Query in `test2.key_word`, then it says `Table 'test2.test2.key_word' doesn't exist`.

Below is how the `test.key_word` table is created

```
CREATE TABLE `key_word` (
 `primary_key` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `indexVal` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hashed_word` char(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key`),
 KEY `hashed_word` (`hashed_word`,`indexVal`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28570982 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Below is how the `test2.key_word` table is created

```
CREATE TABLE `key_word` (
 `primary_key` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `indexVal` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hashed_word` char(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Why this is not getting copied? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use as per below, you have made db and tablename as a single name encsoling by `db.table`.

```
INSERT INTO test2.key_word SELECT * from test.key_word;
```

Note: Make sure no of columns should be same in source and target table.